# Django Not Sending Email

Tags: python, django, email

I am trying to send a mail using Django's `send_mail()` from my local machine but having some challenges.

I have the email settings set in my `settings.py` thusly:

**settings.py**:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = '1025'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
```

**views.py**:

```
def send_greetings(request):
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    send_mail('Invitation', 'Hi, how are you doing today?', 'info@greetings.com', [example@gmail.com], fail_silently=False)
```

If I try the code above, I get:

```
SMTPException at /mysite/
STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

If comment `#EMAIL_USE_TLS = True` in `settings.py` file. It doesn't show any error but I don't receive any email in my Gmail account.

If I change the `EMAIL_PORT = 25` I get:

```
error at /mysite/
[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: Can you send email from your local machine *at all*? If you can't, this is a email server configuration question, not a programming/django one

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked perfectly, try this:

**settings.py**

```
# Change HOST, HOST_USER, and HOST_PASSWORD
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_HOST='mail.example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER='test@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='test123'
EMAIL_PORT=26
```

**views.py**

```
def send_greetings(request):
     ...
     subject = 'email subject'
     message = "Hello"
     from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
     to_email = "youremail@example.com"
     recipient = [to_email]
     send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient, fail_silently=True)
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below. send_mail returns a value which you are not returning in your method.

```
def send_greetings(request):
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    result = send_mail('Invitation', 'Hi, how are you doing today?', 'info@greetings.com', [example@gmail.com], fail_silently=False)
    return result
```